# Youtube Thumbnail Size isn't 100% of iframe in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, iframe

The pic (thumbnail) inside the iframe for the youtube video used to go to the edges of the iframe. Now, without changing any code that would've affected that, the thumbnail stays in the center, miniaturized, and there is black space around it on all sides. This happens regardless of the iframe aspect ratio. The issue is happening in Chrome only and it looks fine in FF.

*Edit - this is happening everywhere, not just my site. It's a Youtube issue.

Comment: Some code would help!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but not been able to figure out what is going on. For example go here http://avexdesigns.com/responsive-youtube-embed/ and open in both firefox and chrome. You will notice the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something just happened with this tonight with the Youtube thumbnails not being expanded to 100% of the video size. I noticed with my embedded videos on Chrome, but you can see it with almost all embedded videos on Chrome or Chrome Canary. The thumbnails are at 100% in Firefox or IE 11. Must be a YouTube issue.